# Ionic 2 Tabs/Footer and InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I use a simple function to open a WebPage in the `InAppBrower`:

```
lauchPage(url) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

        console.log('ready');
        this.iab.create(url);

    })
}
```

But the Browser is launching in FullScreen an my Tabs are hidden. Is the a way to open the `InAppBrowser` just in a specific area in the App. For example in `<ion-content>`?

Comment: maybe take a look at `presentationstyle 'pagesheet' | 'formsheet' | 'fullscreen'` under the [InAppBrowserOptions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/in-app-browser/#InAppBrowserOptions) for IOS only though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Themeable Browser](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/themeable-browser/) and customizing it's height (i haven't tested the plugin, but since you can customize it, probably it'll fit to what you need).

But since you're creating a Page over a page, if someone clicks the tabs, the page probably still continue working in background, i advise you to use the `Platform.resume()` to close the page if something in your app is clicked.

Hope it helps :D